# FB Android: How to ask a publish permission during installation?

Tags: android, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to convert my app to use the new `Facebook Android SDK 3.0`. I want to be able to check in places with my app. I've switched my old log in method to the `native-login` button supplied with the SDK. As far as I understand I can't ask for publishing permission during the installation process without asking for a basic permission first. And I can't set both publish and read permissions to the login button, because this will cause an exception. Then how should I do this? I don't want my user to deal with two dialog screens (every click matters). I want to ask for the permission once during the installation (first time use) process, and not when the publishing will occur (this damages the designed flow of my app).

Thank you in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

- No you cannot ask for Publish Permission during app install (Only basic permission)
- Publish permission dialog will be asked only once
- Your right asking publish permission at install time will throw exception & break the login flow